# Enviar para e-mail diferente de acordo com a hora do dia

Tags: php, html

Como eu faço para enviar um formulário de e-mail para dois e-mails diferentes de acordo com a hora do dia.

Exemplo: Das 00:00 até as 11:00AM o e-mail é enviado para um determinado e-mail e das 12:01PM até as 23:59PM o e-mail seria enviado para outro e-mail.

```
   <?php

date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i');

if (isset($_POST['BTEnvia'])) {

 //Variaveis de POST, Alterar somente se necessário 
 //====================================================
 $nome = $_POST['nome'];
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $telefone = $_POST['telefone']; 
 $mensagem = $_POST['mensagem'];
 //====================================================

 //REMETENTE --> ESTE EMAIL TEM QUE SER VALIDO DO DOMINIO
 //==================================================== 
 $email_remetente = "meuemail@meuemail.com"; // deve ser uma conta de email do seu dominio 
 //====================================================

 //Configurações do email, ajustar conforme necessidade
 //==================================================== 
 $email_destinatario = "meuemail@meuemail.com"; // pode ser qualquer email que receberá as mensagens
 $email_reply = "$email"; 
 $email_assunto = "Contato formmail"; // Este será o assunto da mensagem
 //====================================================

 //Monta o Corpo da Mensagem
 //====================================================
 $email_conteudo = "Nome = $nome \n"; 
 $email_conteudo .= "Email = $email \n";
 $email_conteudo .= "Telefone = $telefone \n"; 
 $email_conteudo .= "Mensagem = $mensagem \n"; 
 //====================================================

 //Seta os Headers (Alterar somente caso necessario) 
 //==================================================== 
 $email_headers = implode ( "\n",array ( "From: $email_remetente", "Reply-To: $email_reply", "Return-Path: $email_remetente","MIME-Version: 1.0","X-Priority: 3","Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8" ) );
 //====================================================

 //Enviando o email 
 //==================================================== 
 if (mail ($email_destinatario, $email_assunto, nl2br($email_conteudo), $email_headers)){ 
 echo "</b>E-Mail enviado com sucesso!</b>"; 
 } 
 else{ 
 echo "</b>Falha no envio do E-Mail!</b>"; } 
 //====================================================
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode fazer a verificação da data com base no DateTime, atribuindo as horas para o meio dia, depois, verificando se a data atual é depois do meio dia. Se sim, altera o e-mail que deve receber o disparo.

```
<?php

$date = new \DateTime();

$date->setTime(12,00,00);

$dateNow = new \DateTime();

$email = 'antesdomeiodia@gmail.com';

if($dateNow > $date) {
    $email = 'depoisdomeiodia@gmail.com';
}

....
```